# How do I take user input and link to corresponding HTML page using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

So, I have a form on my HTML page, and a separate button that links to the form. My question is: when the user enters a certain input (in this case a string) and clicks on the button, how do I connect the user to a different HTML page based on the corresponding user input from the form? I know I have to use javascript, but any specific code will be extremely helpful. Thanks!

ADDDED MY CODE:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Home</title>
    </head>

    <body>
            <form id = "user-info" onSubmit="myFunction()">
                <div class = "favorite-fruit">
                    <p>Enter your favorite fruit<br></p>
                        <input type="text" name="fav-fruit" id = "fruit"><br>
                </div>
                <div class="favorite-vegetable">
                    <p>Enter your favorite vegetable<br></p>
                        <input type="text" name="fav-vegetable" id="vegetable">
                </div>
            </form>
            <a class = "confirm" onSubmit="myFunction()">
                <button form= "user-info" type="button" name= "confirm-input">Confirm</button>
            </a>
        </div>


        <script type="text/javascript">
            function myFunction(){
                var firstFruit = document.getElementById("fruit").innerHTML;
                var secondVegetable = document.getElementById("vegetable").innerHTML;
                var f = firstFruit;
                var s = secondVegetable;

                if(f.value == "Apple" && s.value == "Broccoli"){
                    //GO TO "appleBroccoli.html"
                }
                else if(f.value == "Grapes" && s.value == "Carrots"){
                    //GO TO "grapesCarrots.html"
                }
                else if(f.value == "Strawberry" && s.value == "Kale"){
                    //GO TO "strawberryKale.html"
                }



            }



        </script>
      </body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you please update your code here.

Comment: You really should show us some effort in what you've done. You can read more about creating a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: window.location.href, window.open, form submission

Answer (score 1):

It can be done by taking up the value of input tag like :-

```
var value = $(element).val();
```

Then resetting the action attribute of the form tag with the new value like :-

```
$(formElem).attr("action",value+".html")
```

I guess this would help u..

Comment: He/she seems to be using plain vanilla JS so it'd be better to mention that your suggestion is based on jQuery ;-)
Also, this: `value+".html"` would end up in `Apple.html` or `Broccoli.html` which doesn't seem to be the desired outcome because he wants a fixed/common page for multiple choices. You'd also need some checks in place to avoid things like `fudfud.html` or `0123.html` from happening

Comment: ya sure @FrancescoG. 
the time I answered the question , the code wasn't mentioned.
There after , I explained assuming he/she should get a basic gist of my solution . :)

But anyways , thanks for correcting me .
Will definitely keep such things in mind for future commenting .. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your form, user-info doesnt have a submit button

add `<input type = 'submit' name='conform'>Confirm</input>` inside the form

Set action and method to the form to the corrosponding target HTML page.

```
<form action='..target html' method ='get'>
</form>
```

If the input is brocolli, you can change the form action as

```
document.getElementById('user-info').action = <new target>
```